# Meteor inserting into nested collection?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor

I have a Teams collection which has an creator id and a members array.
After searching for the correct team using the creator id, I want to add items into the members array and in that members array, each spot is another array that holds a string and a number, but am having problem trying to do so.

Currently I'm trying,

```
var user = Meteor.user();
var myTeam = Teams.findOne({creatorId: user._id});
Teams.insert(myTeam, {$addToSet: {members: {someString, someNumber}}});
```

which comes to an error.
What should be the right way to do this? =(

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a team that you want to add members to you have to use `update` on your teams collection and update the document with the id of the desired team:

```
Teams.update({
    _id: myTeam._id
}, {
    $addToSet: {
        members: {
            someString, someNumber
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi PhilippSpo! Thanks for your quick reply. Eh the application failed due to error thou. Hmm... Unexpected token.

Comment: Ah I realised that the final members should be [] instead of {}. Thanks still for helping! =D